# Xst 2927 Proc Common V3 not found

Tags: hardware, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am building a perhieral (called solver) in ISE from the project generated by CIP tool (AXI Slave model with 6 registers). When sythesising the project I get the following error:

```
ERROR:Xst:2927 - "\Users\Sam\Documents\Zynq7020\Solver\Solver.srcs\sources_1\edk\system\pcores\solver_v1_02_a\devl\projnav\solver.prj" line 1: Source file ../../../../../../../../../../../../../Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/hw/XilinxProcessorIPLib/pcores/proc_common_v3_00_a/hdl/vhdl/proc_common_pkg.vhd does not exist
-->
```

This error occurs for all new perherial projects created after the creating the solver project. I do not understand where this error has come from as for all previous perhirals I have built this has never occured, and old perhieral projects still synthesise (so therefore Proc Common v.3.00 are not actually missing!). So I have narrowed it down to being some configuration that has recently been changed in these recent projects (I think).

Of course one quick fix to get it synthesizing is to comment out all of the

```
library proc_common_v3_00_a;
use proc_common_v3_00_a.proc_common_pkg.all;
```

statement in the AXI_LITE, SOFT_RESET and USER_LOGIC modules. But I don't think this is acceptable as I have never had to do this before as previously stated.

Many Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: If I counted dots correctly it is trying to base the Xilinx folder at \Xilinx. Is that where it really is?

Comment: i'm not really sure. I just searched my computer and found that PROC_V3 inside one of my old working projects is in the devl/xst folder for that PCore. So am just going to give that ago!

Comment: that didn't work, and I checked the file path given and the file does exist so completely confused as to why it can't find it!

Comment: Brian, you are right, so I compared the .prj file for an old project and there appears to be two too many ../../ which is leading it to the wrong file path. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix this, as every time I manually write the .prj it gets overwritten at synthesis.

Comment: There has to be a setting for that, but I can't help with that one. You could bodge it with a symlink to the right folder from / (or \\) but that's REALLY the wrong answer!

Comment: Yah there must be, I find over half my design time is taken up battling xilinx tools :( . So to add to the mystery I created a perh using a known XPS project that I have working perhs for, and the new perh works. So I guess now it can be narrowed further as to something new XPS is doing (in new projects) when creating the ISE project that is changing the file root.

Comment: The issue as actually correlated to the directory for the whole embedded project, usually I create them in my user sub-dir, which have worked fine but for this is created in Documents/Zynq7020 subdir and this is obviously where it is getting confused with the extra ../../ from. I guess it must be a software bug! I also run my windows on bootcamp on a mac so maybe that adds to the issue!

Comment: ... half the design time battling tools ... sounds about right on the first pass through a project. And Xilinx isn't especially bad! When you're happy with the result I suggest posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never was able to work out how to fix it (and once again the Xilinx forums prove kind of useless), but as stated above in the comments, it was something to do with using a different path for the planahead project folder other than the usual in the user i.e. Sam/ file space. This causes it to get confused and use the wrong file path.

I suggest simply creating projects back in a folder which has been shown to work in the past!